# Performance : Counting the frequency of specific words using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am reading the words from a hdfs file, which is around 3.3 GB in size and using spark to count the frequency of specific words.

`queryList` is the collection of words whose frequency I have to calculate.

This is my current code

```
//filter
JavaRDD<String> filterFp = textFile.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(String s) throws Exception {
        boolean res = s.equals(queryList.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < queryList.size(); i++) {
            res = res || s.equals(queryList.get(i));
        }
        return res;
    }
});
// map
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> mapper =
        filterFp.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<>(s, 1);
            }
        });

// reduce
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = mapper.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer integer, Integer integer2) throws Exception {
        return integer + integer2;
    }
});
```

The sum of all job times is 5-6 seconds.

Is there any way which I could optimise my task better.

Comment: Your filter is essentially queryList.contains(s) just without short-circuit optimization, which might have quite an impact when queryList is long. Better: convert queryList to a HashSet beforehand and then simply filter for querySet.contains(s).

Comment: `queryList` is < 50 @mtj

Comment: Still try that suggestion. Right now, you have O(n) complexity in the filter alone, which you can reduce to O(1).

Comment: I tried, that didnt help much though , mostly because it was O(50) to O(1)

Comment: Sorry, no more immediate suggestions from my side. Hopefully others have further ideas.

Comment: You can also try tuning your code base on the below queries: Are you running it in local, standalone or cluster mode?
What is the configuration of your cluster, laptop(in case of local mode)?
How many partitions are there in the RDD?